# Why could port 1194 not be accessed while OpenVPN is running?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I installed openVPN on my server.
By default, the port 1194 is choosen.

The problem is that when I am running:

```
sudo nmap -sU localhost -p 1194
```

It shows me:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1194/udp closed openvpn
```

I was trying to:

```
 sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

By running

```
sudo netstat -uapn | grep openvpn
```

I am getting:

```
 udp        0      0 172.16.0.5:1194         0.0.0.0:*                           6788/openvpn
```

But nothing changed. Any idea?

Comment: What do you get from `sudo netstat -apn |grep -w 1194`?

Comment: udp        0      0 172.16.0.5:1194         0.0.0.0:*                           6788/openvpn

Comment: Are you sure it's closed? OpenVPN doesn't respond unless the packet is valid, so even if it gets through the firewall the scan may not get a reply. Have you tried with an OpenVPN client?

Comment: I have tryed to run telnet to the specific port and I got a timeout. Maybe this is the problem, I will ask a colleague to try with a OpenVPN client.

Comment: Telnet is tcp .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your `nmap` to `172.16.0.5` instead of `localhost` or change the `--local` option on the `openvpn` command line or config.  By default, `openvpn` should listen on all interfaces for `udp/1194`.

Running:

```
nmap -sU localhost -p 1194
```

could result in:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-14 04:14 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up.
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
1194/udp open|filtered unknown
```

Comment: I think you've hit it, because we know from his `netstat` output above that it's only listening on the `172.16.0.5` address.

Comment: Had to look up your grep -w ...

Comment: @dmourati if a random port is choosen it always result in `filtered unknown` even when the firewall is closed. To check whether openvpn is accessible it should return `filtered openvpn`. Stopping it and running nmap again results in `1194/udp closed openvpn`